# @PropertyId annotation "is disallowed for this location"

Tags: java, vaadin

I got this error and just can't seem to find how to get it working.
My code, simply following some Vaadin10+ exercises:

```java
@PropertyId("string")
final TextField stringField = new TextField("A simple string");
```

and this won't compile, highlighting the annotation telling the error I put as a title of this question. Compilation error doesn't tell anything more.

Any idea of why it doesn't work? For reference, this is a maven project in eclipse (LTS) and Java 8, and I don't lack any dependency in the pom since I copied the working copy of the pom from the exercise files archive.

Anyway, I'd only need this to do bean validation with javax validators, so I don't *need* it that hard. I'd just like to understand why it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're referring to happens e.g. when an annotation declared to be used on methods is instead used on e.g. a class or an instance field.

`@PropertyId` in Vaadin is defined with `@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })` which means that it should be used for instance fields. Since you are not showing the full context of the code that causes the problem, I can imagine two potential causes:

1. Your `stringField` is a local variable inside a method instead of being an instance field in a class.
2. You're accidentally importing some other `@PropertyId` annotation instead of the intended one from `com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.PropertyId`.

Comment: Oh yeah. Exactly that. As you can see I'm defining it directly here and not as a top-level field. I didn't know what they meant by `@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })` when I saw it in the `@interface PropertyId`'s code. Thank you very much!